# Gradle build failed in unity2018

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

I can not build with gradle in unity. I have unity 2018.2.10.
When I build my project with gradle in unity, the following error is shown in the console.

> My jdk: "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191"

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Unity2018_setup\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\proj\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.
> Could not find method mavenCenter() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I have used mavenCenteral as well. Can I need to access to the Internet to build?

My main template is like below:

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}

android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem,
file-> build setting-> player setting -> publishing setting -> build system set to internal
good luck

Comment: I say gradle. You say internal?!! I know internal build system is OK!