# Android Platform - Gradle Build Failed - What does the error mean

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Error message 1:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0a10\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Error message 2:

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Error Message 3:

BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Error Inside of Console Editor:

stderr[
D8: Program type already present: com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 38s
]
stdout[
:checkReleaseClasspath
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:checkReleaseManifest
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:prepareLintJar
:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
:processReleaseManifest
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease FAILED
21 actionable tasks: 21 executed
]
exit code: 1
  at UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00031] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00015] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x0000a] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) [0x0001f] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) [0x00021] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
  at UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) [0x00042] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x000a8] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00074] in <4c5a816e27224218a2785a0505447762>:0 
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck()
UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:172)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods(Boolean, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun(Boolean) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:130)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:124)

Comment: That isn't the error. The actual error is after `stderr[` in the log.

Comment: @RetiredNinja What is this telling me is wrong though?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't shown what the actual error is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja What exactly do I need to provide to help you see? This is an error that occurs when I try to Build and Run from Unity to my mobile phone. This problem started when I implemented Unity Ads with the Monetaztion3.0.1. Using test mode, it works inside of Unity; however, build and run will go to the very end but fail. I get 3 errors in my console. I'll edit my topic with the other two now.

Comment: Also note that I deleted the Monetazation from my project after disabling the built in ads feature. Then re-imported the monetization plug-in. That's exactly when the build and run would no longer work. I even tried to enable test mode and enable the built in ads again. I also changed "test_mode" variable to true inside of the code.

Comment: When you select the error message in the console the full excerpt from your log is printed in another pane below it. You need top copy all of the text from that pane and read the part after `stderr[` to see the actual Gradle error. It will look like the top part of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659720/gradle-build-failed-in-unity2018

Comment: @RetiredNinja Where is this extra panel located? I do not see it?

Comment: Ok, I found a feature called "Open Editor log" Here's the error that you requested. stderr[
D8: Program type already present: com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have edited my topic. Please let me know if I need to provide more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity 2018.3 android dex merging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997487/unity-2018-3-android-dex-merging-issue)

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate of that thread. I'm using 2019.0.a10 for starters. Apparently my issue was due to the plugin not properly imported either by my fault or the engine's. Then it was a matter of following steps to insure the plugin was properly imported. To be safe, I deleted the unity ads, closed out the project and logged back in. Then re-imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this issue I had to do the following steps in this order:

1. Delete Unity Ads plugin within the project
2. Save project and close Unity
3. Open Unity, the project I'm working on
4. In the services tab, turn off Unity Ads
5. Re-Import the Monetization 3.0.1 plugin
6. In the services tab, turn on Unity Ads
7. Make sure that Enable Builtin Ads is unchecked

Note- I'm using Unity 2019.1.0.a10 (Which I don't advise anyone else to use because the safer upgraded version is available now).